# Data Set of Bourguignon and Morrison 2002 AER

Tags: gdp, data-request, inequality

This question is about the following paper:

F. Bourguignon and C. Morrison "Inequality among World Citizens: 1820-1992", *American Economic Review*, Vol. 92, No. 4. (Sep., 2002), pp. 727-744.

On p.730, the authors say that

> The data, data sources, and assumptions behind them are available at:
>   (http://www.delta.ens.fr/XIX).

But the link is dead.

Does anyone know where their data can be accessed /downloaded?

P.S. I am interested in data which were used in calculating Gini and other indices reported in the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wayback machine has snapshots: https://web.archive.org/web/20120217010359/http://www.delta.ens.fr/XIX/